# Analyzing ROS messages

Tags: ros, message, msg, rostopic, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a command that will allow me to see what is stored in specific messages? I know rxgraph shows where everything is going but is there something similar to what is being sent?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9465/analyzing-ros-messages/) by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2011-03-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use `rostopic` to print the contents of a message to standard output. For example,

```
rostopic echo /camera/image_raw
```

will echo the *full contents* of the `/camera/image_raw` topic. If the message contains binary data, such as with `Image`, this will likely cause problems with your terminal emulator. In those cases it is useful to only echo the fields of interest:

```
rostopic echo /camera/image_raw/width /camera/image_raw/height
```

I don't believe that there is a graphical (`rx`...) analog `rostopic`.

---

Originally posted by [mkoval](https://answers.ros.org/users/309/mkoval/) with karma: 524 on 2011-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-03-17**:
The graphical version of "rostopic echo" is "rxplot".

**Comment by [mkoval](https://answers.ros.org/users/309/mkoval/) on 2011-03-17**:
Very good point. I never thought of RViz as a method of seeing the contents of a message, but that is its sole purpose.

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2011-03-17**:
Perhaps rviz would be the graphical analogy of rostopic?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [rosmsg](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosmsg) tool will show you all of the fields available for a given message type. For example, to see all of the fields available in the nav_msgs/Odometry message type, you would use the following:

```
rosmsg show nav_msgs/Odometry
```

Note that that page shows how you can use this to easily get the fields available on a given topic using something like:

```
rostopic type <topic_name> | rosmsg show
```

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-03-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rxbag --record /topic` will allow you to see what's stored in messages published on a topic.  You can view the contents textually, plot numerical values, or view image messages.

---

Originally posted by [Tim Field](https://answers.ros.org/users/297/tim-field/) with karma: 191 on 2011-03-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on 2011-03-18**:
How would you go around viewing those recorded messages textually, plotted, or image messages.

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-03-17**:
Cool, I didn't know you could record with rxbag, nor plot the data being recorded as it comes in!